# Is it possible to access non db key from request in Django signal?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing an api request and I'm sending a non-db key with the request.

In Django's pre-signal I want to use that key to make a decision.

Is it possible to do it? If yes how can I do it?

*Example Scenario:*

```
# POST request body from postman
{
  "field1": 10,
  "custom_field": True
}

# test model
class TestModel(models.Model):
  field1 = model.IntegerField(default=0)
  field2 = model.CharField(default="test")

# django pre save signal
pre_save.connect(test_function, sender=TestModel)

# test function in some helper
def test_function(sender, instance, raw, using,
                                       update_fields, **extra_fields):
  # here I'm using the custom field which is not in model
  if instance.custom_field:
    instance.field2 = "hello"
  else:
    instance.field2 = "hi"
```

I'm getting an error i.e. `AttributeError: 'ModelTest' object has no attribute 'custom_field'`

I hope you understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `./manage syncdb` ?

Comment: You are trying to access `custom_field` on your `TestModel` which doesn't have this field. I don't get it.

Comment: @pako as I shown in example, I want to make some decision based on that field. So I want to access that field in the Django signal. and yes that field is not in `TestModel`.

Comment: @VishalNagda: did you assign that attribute to your model instance before calling `.save()`? Show the code when you are saving/updating model.

Comment: yes you can, as @pako mentioned you can assign any attribute to a python object. But you need to do that before you save the instance. Also, in your test_function, you cannot be sure that this attribute has been set, so you should check first, since it's not part of your model. Or you could set it as a default class attribute, which would be better.

Comment: @pako I'm not sure how to assign that attribute to the model instance. Can you please elaborate with some example or share some article related to that. So I can learn this concept.

We are using serializer to validate the data and I can access that attribute in serializer's create function `self.initial_data.get('custom_field', None)` and we're using get_or_create to save data.

`asset_object, created = TestModel.objects.get_or_create(
            **validated_data)`

can I do something here?

Comment: So for example when you have `created` object (from your comment) this is instance. You have to assign `created.custom_field = self.initial_data.get('custom_field', None)` and then inside your `test_function()` you could check if that value exists `if hasattr(instance, 'custom_field')`. That's it.

Comment: @pako `created.custom_field = self.initial_data.get('custom_field', None)` throwing error because it's a bool. and if I do `asset_object.custom_field = self.initial_data.get('custom_field', None)` this is also not working.
As per @anjaneyulu-batta 's answer if I override `save` function then I can access the `custom_field` in the `pre_signal`'s instance. But now the question is how to pass it in the get_or_create method so I can access it in `pre_signal`'s instance.

Comment: Sorry, should be `asset_object` not `created`. The rest should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments in `.save()` method.

Something like this: `product.save(update_fields=['name'])`
Note: It isn't necessary that you pass model fields only.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Answer (score 1):

You do the magic with the `save` method like below

```py
class TestModel(models.Model):
  field1 = model.IntegerField(default=0)
  field2 = model.CharField(default="test")

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.custom_field = kwargs.pop('custom_field', None)
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```